# YouTube API v2.0 deprecated ECL Tridion youtube ecl provider Fails - unable to open component

Tags: 2013, ecl

YouTube API v2.0 deprecated ECL youtube_ecl_provider integration Fails -> please refer to https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/youtube_ecl_provider.aspx .

Please let us know is there updated  you tube provider code available or we need to re implement the provider code to support version (3).

We would  like to know  more details on this before we implement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be a great contribution to the community if you can get it out the Anand :)

Comment: You mention YouTube API v2 is deprecated, but what exactly is the issue with that? Deprecation does not necessarily mean it stops working. Furthermore the YouTube ECL provider is delivered without source, so you should ask its creator (James Simm from Building Blocks) for an update, or write a new one yourself.

Comment: Bart, Google only keep deprecated APIs working until a year after they are deprecated, so its likely its stopped working entirely at this point.

Comment: As we well know from our experiences with Chrome :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemented the support for youtube v3, I forked James Simm's source and build on top of it. The source can be found at https://github.com/kpmrafeeq/youtube-ecl-provider

There are few issues that were faced during implementation for the paginated result

- Google support maximum 50 results at a time
- Google changed the way we were retrieving the list with pagination
- With v3 google supports only forward and backward pagination, this works like some thing called as PageToken, and it is a token page index; It gets only with currently each request.
- I just added a work around for this, but its not good for a large list. let me know if anybody have better suggestion on this, so that I can update it

Comment: Had to do minor fix to your provider to get it working i have submitted the changes on github.

Answer (score 5):

The YouTube ECL provider on [Tridion World](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/youtube_ecl_provider.aspx) has the source code in the package zip, which you could update to use the newer YouTube API.

The provider was created for a specific project and hasn't really been looked at in a while. When I get a chance, I'll have a look at updating it to the newer API.

However, I can't promise when this will be, as I'm working on other projects currently.

I have put the code up on [Building Blocks' Github organisation](https://github.com/buildingblocks/youtube-ecl-provider) and I'm very happy to accept pull requests for it.

You'd need to remove the [YouTube GData nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.GData.YouTube/), and its dependencies and install the newer [Google APIs Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/), making any necessary changes to the code.

There are some good code samples samples on the [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet).

Sorry I can't give you an updated version, but hope this helps.

Comment: James Simm thank you so much for your response really appreciated.  We will look into it and will update you guys after we make the provider work for version 3.0. Again thanks for your reply.

Comment: @AnandNS - does this answer the question (as it seems to to me) - if so, please mark it as answered :)